# c# linq .First and .Last working properly, .Max throws 'Sequence contains no elements'

Tags: c#, linq

Code is:

```
    _currentTime = UnixTimestamps.RoundTimestamp1(CsvLastLineAggTimestamp(cryptoPair, "agg"));
    _tempAgg = File.ReadAllLines("agg" + @cryptoPair + ".csv")
                                .Select(v => AggTradesClass.FromCsv(v)).ToList();                  
    _nextFiveInterval = UnixTimestamps.RoundTimestamp1(_tempAgg[0].T) + 60000;
    _timeFiveInterval = _nextFiveInterval - 60000;
    while (_nextFiveInterval <= _currentTime)
    {                        
        open = _tempAgg.Where(itm => itm.T >= _timeFiveInterval).First().p;
        close = _tempAgg.Where(itm => itm.T < _nextFiveInterval).Last().p;
        high = _tempAgg.Where(itm => itm.T >= _timeFiveInterval).Where(itm => itm.T < _nextFiveInterval).Max(itm => itm.p);
        low = _tempAgg.Where(itm => itm.T >= _timeFiveInterval).Where(itm => itm.T < _nextFiveInterval).Min(itm => itm.p);
        _tempOHLC.Add(new OHLC() { timestamp = _timeFiveInterval });

        foreach (var itm in _tempOHLC.Where(item => item.timestamp == _timeFiveInterval))
        {
            itm.high = high;
            itm.low = low;
            itm.open = open;
            itm.close = close;
        }
    _nextFiveInterval += 60000;
    _timeFiveInterval += 60000;
}
```

so the line
`close = _tempAgg.Where(itm => itm.T < _nextFiveInterval).Last().p;` doesn't make any problem but line below `high = _tempAgg.Where(itm => itm.T >= _timeFiveInterval).Where(itm => itm.T < _nextFiveInterval).Max(itm => itm.p);` in what seems to be the last iteration of while loop, throws error:

*Message=Sequence contains no elements Source=System.Core StackTrace: at System.Linq.Enumerable.Max(IEnumerable`1 source) at System.Linq.Enumerable.Max[TSource](IEnumerable1 source, Func2 selector) at method...*

Comment: You cannot do `Min` or `Max` on an empty collection. You need at least 1 value in the collection. see [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.min?view=net-5.0)

Comment: Think your trying to get the max value of strings. Need to convert to some sort of numeric type first.

Comment: Franck - it's not empty -`Last` and `First` work swell in that iteration.

Comment: John Wu - it's float, not string..

Comment: The `Last` doesn't throw an exception because that query is different than the one you use for the `Max`. For the latter you append another `Where`, so another condition, obviously there is no item matching the condition `itm.T < _nextFiveInterval`.

Comment: `close` is calculated with a single where condition, `high` use two conditions: I assume the resutlts are different. Try to call Count() on the result of the second query before calling .Max(): is it 0 or what else?

Comment: Tim Schmelter - you are onto something. when I do this:
```open = _tempAgg.Where(itm => itm.T >= _timeFiveInterval).Where(itm => itm.T < _nextFiveInterval).First().p;

                    close = _tempAgg.Where(itm => itm.T >= _timeFiveInterval).Where(itm => itm.T < _nextFiveInterval).Last().p;

                    high = _tempAgg.Where(itm => itm.T >= _timeFiveInterval).Where(itm => itm.T < _nextFiveInterval).Max(itm => itm.p);

                    low = _tempAgg.Where(itm => itm.T >= _timeFiveInterval).Where(itm => itm.T < _nextFiveInterval).Min(itm => itm.p);
```
error on open now

Comment: Last and First will also fail on the collection where Max fails. Comparing behavior of different methods on different sets of data is not very practical. Side note- I’m not sure what is expected result of filtering list to have only items that are at the same time bigger and smaller than the given value- some clarification may help

Comment: Alexei Levenkov - it's list of ohlc data - open high low close - for candlestick charts for stock trading.
problem is somewhere as Tim Schmelter first pointed out - there is no data to check in that interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says it all. There is no element that matches your query. So no item with T like itm.T >= _timeFiveInterval and itm => itm.T < _nextFiveInterval.
You should check if there is element before calling max or min

Comment: Yes, in that specific interval, there was no data to fetch - which I thought was impossible to happen. Ty and tnx Tim Schmelter for responding quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Let's materialize this instead of repeating this query over and over:

```
while (_nextFiveInterval <= _currentTime)
{
    var c = _tempAgg.Where(itm => itm.T >= _timeFiveInterval && itm.T < _nextFiveInterval)
      .Select(item => item.p)
      .ToArray();

    if(!c.Any()) //no elements
      continue;
          
    open = c.First();
    close = c.Last();
    high = c.Max();
    low = c.Min();
```

It's actually readable now! :)

Comment: You won't believe what the problem actually was: I thought it's impossible in 1 minute interval that no one will trade specific pair - and just that happened..
now I need to implement fail safe, if no one traded in selected interval - just use same open high low close data from last interval...

Comment: This is golden code. it will save me a lot of lines. Maybe not lines, but certainly characters.